# How to increase the number of check in places with Facebook API Graph on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to increase the number of check in places with Facebook API Graph on iOS.

I'm using the Hackbook sample and currently there are only 5 places to check in displayed in the UITableView.

the following method has a distance parameter, but I couldn't find a checkin number of places to return...

```
/*
 * Graph API: Search query to get nearby location.
 */
- (void)apiGraphSearchPlace:(CLLocation *)location {
    [self showActivityIndicator];
    currentAPICall = kAPIGraphSearchPlace;
    NSString *centerLocation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",
                                location.coordinate.latitude,
                                location.coordinate.longitude];
    HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"place",  @"type",
                                   centerLocation, @"center",
                                   @"3000",  @"distance",
                                   nil];
    [centerLocation release];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"search" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it in the **`- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result`** method:

```
case kAPIGraphSearchPlace:
        {
            NSMutableArray *places = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
            NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[resultData count] && i < 15; i++) {
                [places addObject:[resultData objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            // Show the places nearby in a new view controller
            APIResultsViewController *controller = [[APIResultsViewController alloc]
                                                initWithTitle:@"Check In"
                                                data:places
                                                action:@"places"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
            [places release];
            break;
        }
```